# $a^{1/n}$ - How do you explain it cannot be $0$ for $a > 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you explain formally, $a^{1/n}$ cannot be equal to $0$ for every $a > 0$?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $b=a^{1/n}$, we have $b^n=a$. Now, can $0^n=a>0$?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an $a > 0 $ such that $a^{1/n} = 0 $, then $a = 0 $. False

Answer (score 1):

$a^{\frac{1}{n}}=b \Rightarrow a=b^n \Rightarrow b^n>0 \Rightarrow? b=0$???

Answer (score 1):

Because $a^{1/n}$ as a function of $a$ , takes the value $0$ at $0$ and it is increasing in $(a, \infty)$:

If $a>0$ , then $a^{1/n}=e^{n\log a}$; $\frac{d}{da}e^{n\log a}=ne^{n\log a}$ . Now, if you accept that $e^x$ is positive , and that $0^{1/n}=0$, then $e^{n\log a}$ is positive, so that $a^{1/n}$ is strictly increasing (in $(0,\infty)$ where $\log a$ is defined), and takes the value $0$ at $0$, so that it must be larger than $0$ in $(0, \infty)$.